# c# server-client, client doesnt reconnect

Tags: c#, server, client

thanks in advance for anything.
Im making a server-client program, in which the server(application) creates a server and the client connects to it, i will also have a textbox and a button on the server application and whenever i write something on that textbox and press the button, it will send to the client application(there is only a textbox in this application, the only thing this application does is receive strings from the server application).

I think it works, kinda, but not the way i want it.
I can make the connection and also send and receive the information from the textboxs, but only if i run the server application first(to create the server). The problem is that if i dont run the server application first(to create the server), the client application won't connect, or even try to.

Example of "Error"(i guess you can call it an error):
If i run the client application first and then the server application, the client application just won't connect to the server that the server application created, i made a loop that basically verifies if the client is cnnected, if it is then it starts receiving the information, if not(else) waits for 3 seconds and tries to reconnect again. but when it tries to reconnect it doesnt work.
Any ideas?

CODE IN C#:

```
    public Form1()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) //connect to server
    {
        client = new TcpClient();
        IPEndPoint IP_End = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.254.34"), 123); // sincronizacao do IP com a porta
        try
        {

            Socket socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.254.34"), 123, null, null);
            bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000, true);

            while (success)
            {

                if (client.Connected)
                {

                    STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
                    STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
                    STW.AutoFlush = true;

                    backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // Começar a receber dados em background
                    backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // possibilidade de cancelar o fio

                }
                else
                {

                    int milliseconds = 3000;
                    Thread.Sleep(milliseconds);
                    MessageBox.Show("swag do elias!");

                    client.Connect(IP_End);
                }
            }


        }
        catch (SocketException exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("O erro é:", exception.Source);
        }
    }

    private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) // Receber dados
    {
        while(client.Connected) //enquanto o cliente tiver conectado vai ler o que servidor diz em chat 
        {
            try
            {
                receive = STR.ReadLine();
                this.textBox2.Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate () { textBox2.Text=(receive + "\n\r"); }));
                receive = "";
            }
            catch(Exception x)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(x.Message.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: By the way the code that i put in the Question is from the Client Application

Comment: The server has to be listening before the client can connect.   You cannot start the client first otherwise you will get an error.  This is the way TCP works.

Comment: so what you are saying is that there is no way that i can make the client go first and make him wait till the server runs?... because this is what i pretended to do... make the client go firstand make him search for the server that the server application created and until the server is not created the client should just continue searching till it is created... is it not possible?

Comment: The client will time out if there is no server to connect.  You could periodically ping the server until it responds and then connect.

Answer (score 0):

If the server isn't running yet, then success is always going to be false as a result of this line:

```
bool success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000, true);
```

Since success will always be false, the code inside of your while(success) block will never be executed.

Rearranging your code to something like this might be helpful:

```
client = new TcpClient();

bool success = false;
while (success == false)
{
    try
    {
        IAsyncResult result = client.BeginConnect(IPAddress.Parse("192.168.254.34"), 123, null, null);
        success = result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(3000, true);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        success = false;
        MessageBox.Show("error connecting: " + ex.Message + " : " + ex.StackTrace);
    }
}

// NOW, by the time you reach this point, you KNOW that success == true and that you're connected, and you can proceed with the rest of your code

STW = new StreamWriter(client.GetStream());
STR = new StreamReader(client.GetStream());
STW.AutoFlush = true;

backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync(); // Começar a receber dados em background
backgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true; // possibilidade de cancelar o fio
```

Comment: Did it work for you?, because i tried the way you said and i still didnt get the result im looking for :/